# Protocol <NAME> can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Tags: swift, generics

#### Desc

I have found a few StackOverflow questions for this compile error message but none of answers helped me.

From the beginning, I defined an ViewModel protocol:

```
protocol FormVMProtocol: FormCellVMsProvider {

    associatedtype RequestModel: GatewayObjectRequestModel

    weak var delegate: EventFromVMDelegate? { get set }

    var handleDidCancelForm: (() -> ())? { get set }
    var handleDidAcceptForm: ((RequestModel) -> ())? { get set }

    var title: String { get }

    var cellsViewModels: [EventFormCellVMProtocol] { get }
    var numberOfRows: Int { get }

    func viewModelForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> EventFormCellVMProtocol
    func handleDidSelectRow(at indexPath: IndexPath)

    func getIndexPath(for rowViewModel: EventFormCellVMProtocol) -> IndexPath?
    func refreshRow(with viewModel: EventFormCellVMProtocol)
    func refreshAllRows()

    func createRequestModel() -> Promise<RequestModel>

    func cancelForm()
    func sendForm() -> Promise<()>
}
```

with extension:

```
extension FormVMProtocol {

    var numberOfRows: Int {
        return cellsViewModels.count
    }

    func viewModelForRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> EventFormCellVMProtocol {
        return cellsViewModels[indexPath.row]
    }

    func handleDidSelectRow(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        viewModelForRow(at: indexPath).onSelected?()
    }

    func cancelForm() {
        handleDidCancelForm?()
    }

    func sendForm() -> Promise<()> {
        return createRequestModel()
            .then {
                self.handleDidAcceptForm?($0)
            }
    }

    func getIndexPath(for rowViewModel: EventFormCellVMProtocol) -> IndexPath? {
        guard let index = cellsViewModels.index(where: { rowViewModel === $0 }) else { return nil }

        return IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
    }

    func refreshRow(with viewModel: EventFormCellVMProtocol) {
        guard let indexPath = getIndexPath(for: viewModel) else { return }

        delegate?.reloadRow(at: indexPath)
    }

    func refreshAllRows() {
        delegate?.reloadAllRows()
    }
}
```

then I created ViewController:

```
final class AddEventFormVC: BaseTileVC {

    private var bottomButtonsStackView: UIStackView!
    private var cancelButton: CustomButton!
    private var acceptButton: CustomButton!
    private var tableView: UITableView!

    private let viewModel: FormVMProtocol

    init(viewModel: FormVMProtocol) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        buildUI()
        viewModel.delegate = self
    }
}

///REST OF VC IS NOT IMPORTANT FOR THIS QUESTION
```

Now, my idea is to create a lot of `FormVMProtocol` subclasses and inject them into `AddEventFormVC` to reuse one time created VC.

For example (one of them):

```
final class NoteEventFormVM: FormVMProtocol {

    typealias RequestModel = NoteEvent.InsertRequestModel

    weak var delegate: EventFromVMDelegate?

    var handleDidCancelForm: (() -> ())?
    var handleDidAcceptForm: ((RequestModel) -> ())?

    private let databaseHelper: DatabaseHelperProtocol
    private let authorizationService: AuthorizationServiceProtocol

    private lazy var noteTypeCellVM: EventFormSelectedValueCellVM<AddEventNoteTypeSelectionModel> = {
        return provideFormSelectedValueCellVM(title: "Note Type".localized)
    }()
    private lazy var commentCellVM: EventFormStringDataCellVM = {
        return provideFormStringDataCellVM(title: "Comment".localized)
    }()
    private lazy var eventDateCellVM: EventFormDateCellVM = {
        return provideFormDateCellVM(title: "Event Date")
    }()

    lazy var cellsViewModels: [EventFormCellVMProtocol] = {
        return [noteTypeCellVM, commentCellVM, eventDateCellVM]
    }()

    var title: String {
        return "Notes".localized
    }

    init(databaseHelper: DatabaseHelperProtocol,
         authorizationService: AuthorizationServiceProtocol) {

        //INIT
    }

    func createRequestModel() -> Promise<RequestModel> {
        //PROVIDE RequestModel
    }
}
```

I want to noticed that I specified here the `associatedtype` as `NoteEvent.InsertRequestModel`

Example of usage:

```
    let vm: FormVMProtocol

    switch eventType {
    case .note:
        vm = NoteEventFormVM()
    default:
        //rest of event types
    }

    vm.handleDidCancelForm = { [weak self] in
        let _ = self?.navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    let eventFromVC = AddEventFormVC(viewModel: vm)
    navigationController.pushViewController(eventFromVC, animated: true)
```

#### Problem

In my `AddEventFormVC` compiler is saying

`Protocol 'FormVMProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

I have no idea how to satisfy the compiler.

#### Edit 1

@Jack, `FormCellVMsProvider` helps building cellVMs. I think it is no important in this case but you can check an implementation:

```
protocol FormCellVMsProvider: class {

    func reloadSelectionValueCellVM<T>(_ cellVM: EventFormSelectedValueCellVM<T>, using fetchMethod: () -> Promise<[T]>, selectInitalValue: Bool) -> Promise<()>

    func provideFormDateCellVM(title: String) -> EventFormDateCellVM
    func provideFormSelectedValueCellVM<T: SelectionDialogRenderable>(title: String) -> EventFormSelectedValueCellVM<T>
    func provideFormStringDataCellVM(title: String) -> EventFormStringDataCellVM
}
```

#### Edit 2

OK I achieved something. I changed my VC to generic version:

```
final class AddEventFormVC<T: FormVMProtocol>: BaseVC {

    private let viewModel: T

    init(viewModel: T) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // REST OF VC
}
```

And compile allow me to use it in this way:

```
let vm = NoteEventFormVM()
let vc = EventFormVC(viewModel: vm)

navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

There is still one problem. I can't take advantage of protocols:

```
let vm: FormVMProtocol
vm.handleCancel = { //CODE }
vm.handleSuccess = { //CODE }

switch eventType {
case .note:
    vm = NoteEventFormVM()
case .custom:
    vm = CustomEventFromVM()
default:
    //rest of event types
}

let vc = AddEventFormVC()
navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

because in line `let vm: FormVMProtocol` compiler is shouting `Protocol <NAME> can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

I need to copy/past my code through cases:

```
switch eventType {
case .note:
    let vm = NoteEventFormVM()
    vm.handleCancel = { //CODE }
    vm.handleSuccess = { //CODE }

    let vc = AddEventFormVC()
    navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
case .custom:
    let vm = CustomEventFromVM()
    vm.handleCancel = { //CODE }
    vm.handleSuccess = { //CODE }

    let vc = AddEventFormVC()
    navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
default:
    //rest of event types
}
```

I am looking for better solution.

Comment: What is `FormCellMSProvder`?

Comment: Edited my question, thx for time time. :)

Comment: Why did you deleted your own answer if the initial question was addressed? Note that ongoing questions do not fit the SO format.

Comment: Check my question’s edit. Initial problem still exist.

Comment: I found only workaround. I hope some provide better solution. If any exist